# matplotlib: Don't compress plot in the horizontal direction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to matplotlib and I am having some difficulty with this figure:

[image]

I have a text file with x y point groups that I should plot. However, the x points overlap in each group, so I add an offset to each x axis point for each group.

Usually, the single groups look like this:

[image]
[image]

Note that the x axis in the first image ends where the x-axis in the second image begins.

My problem is that the resulting image is squelched/compressed and not really "readable".

I tried increasing the value that is added to the x-axis for each group/image, but it just compresses each group even more.

I tried suggestions to use `rcParams` or set the `dpi` value of the resulting image, but nothing does the job:

```
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 50, 100
plt.savefig('result.png', dpi=200,pad_inches=5)
```

What am I doing wrong or looking for?

PS: The data and code is [here](https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2015/tree/master/volgactf-quals-2015/stego/strange-text). To see what my problem is, call `python2.7 plotit.py text.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you don't like your image being too compressed in the horizontal direction. It happens because by default `matplotlib` chooses the aspect ratio necessary to fill the given figure size. You were on the right track with changing changing `figsize`, but if you want to change it in `rcParams`, you have to put this call somewhere **before you start plotting.** The other approach is to use the stateless API, that is `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,2)); s = fig.add_subplot(111); s.plot(...)`. That's what you get:

```
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 2
```

[image]

Note that I shrunk the circle sizes to make the lines more distinguishable:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,s=1)
if px!='':
    plt.plot([px,x],[py,y],'-o',markersize=1)
```

For a more accurate control you can actually set the aspect ratio directly:

```
plt.axes().set_aspect(1)
```

[image]

or use some of the predefined modes, e.g.

```
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

*Edit:* for the reference, full code for the final picture:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 2

def parsexydata(fdata):
    keys=[]
    xy=[]
    with open(fdata,'r') as f:
        pre=''
        for idx, i in enumerate(f.read().replace('\n','').split(',')[2:]):
            if idx%2==0:
                pre=i
                continue
            tmp = pre.split('.')
            if len(tmp)!=3: continue
            [before,key,after] = pre.split('.')
            pre = before+'.'+after
            if key not in keys: keys.append(key)
            xy.append([pre,i,key])
    return [xy,keys]

[xydata, keys] = parsexydata(sys.argv[1])

for idx, k in enumerate(keys):
    px=py=''
    for [x,y,key] in xydata:
        if key!=k: continue
        x=float(x)+float(k)
        if key=='01': print(x)
        plt.scatter(x,y,s=1)
        if px!='':
            plt.plot([px,x],[py,y],'-o',markersize=1)
        px,py=x,y

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('result.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks! What is `matplotlib.use('Agg')` doing, though?

Comment: `matplotlib` needs an explicit backend selection for `pyenv` installations on OSX, otherwise it complains about non-franework Python. I usually remove it before posting an answer, just forgot this time.

Comment: Just a quick Q: How would you describe the question? It seems like my question description is very bad and confusing, maybe you can help out! Edit: I edited the title to fit your understanding of the question.